# Azure Web Role recycles, can't load entry point "ExecuteAsync()" in ChallengeResult.cs

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

So, this has worked like forever (and continues to work just fine in emulator).

When I spin up my classic cloud service in Azure I get the error below. `ExecuteAsync()` is in the web role, in `Results/ChallengeResult.cs` (a folder I hadn't even noticed until now).

```
 Role entrypoint could not be created:
 System.TypeLoadException: Unable to load the role entry point due to the following exceptions:
-- System.TypeLoadException: Method 'ExecuteAsync' in type 
'MyWebRole.Results.ChallengeResult' from assembly 'MyWebRole, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
```

When I looked, ChallengeResult.cs does indeed have an implementation for `ExecuteAsync()`. This is the default implementation and its signature is this:

```
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I RDP'd in and used Azure Tools to run `windbg`; it didn't provide any clues. I suspect there's a DLL somewhere that's expecting a different signature.

But which one? Who calls this?

Odd thing is, the service actually works even though the role is recycling.

Comment: Did you solve this Barry? I'm receiving the same error

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue. For some reason a binding redirect was in effect for `System.Net.Http` which caused the issue.

To solve it, I have made a copy of my web.config, renamed it to MyProjectName.dll.config and set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`. 
You can automate this operation with `BeforeBuild` in csproj. You can check [WebRole entry point and config file](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2014/05/15/webrole-entry-point-and-config-file/) for more info.